# ASP.Net Label control's Text property not updating text under button click event

Tags: asp.net, sharepoint-2010, label

I have developed a small application in SharePoint. I am using custom application page and load .ascx Control over that page under Page_Load() method. In .ascx Control, I have created a small form with text boxes and a button Control. under this button click event, I want to change the text property of label like: lblConfirmation.Text = "**Confirmation is OK**"; but it did not change the text. It shows nothing because i set text property empty in label Control.

```
<asp:Label ID="lblConfirmation" runat="server" Text="" ></asp:Label>
```

Any Idea, what is wrong ?

Answer (score 0):

What are this single quotes in your **asp:Label** definition ? please check this

```
<'asp:Label ID="lblConfirmation" runat="server" Text="" ><'/asp:Label>
```

it must be replaced by

```
    <asp:Label ID="lblConfirmation" runat="server" Text="" ></asp:Label>
```

Try to debug the code in your visual studio and let us know if you get any error ?
Thanks

Comment: i use these single quotes myself here in question only because due to some unknown reasons, tage <> are not able to shown until i put single quotes. But In my code, I use exactly this:        <asp:Label ID="lblConfirmation" runat="server" Text="" ></asp:Label> problem is still there ?